SwiftUI - NavigationLink and .navigationDestination: Bindings get updated but views don't refresh
So I was updating my app to the new NavigationStack with .navigationDestination() and giving Bindings as parameters but now views don't refresh although the values get modified.
I feel like I am missing something very basic here:
@main
struct testApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = MyModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(/*path: $path*/) {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Binding<MyData>.self) { data in
                        Content2(data: data)
                    }
            }
            .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}

extension Binding: Equatable where Value: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Binding<Value>, rhs: Binding<Value>) -> Bool {
        lhs.wrappedValue == rhs.wrappedValue
    }
}

extension Binding: Hashable where Value: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.wrappedValue.hashValue)
    }
}


The environment object only contains a @Publised struct with only a var value: Int and an id

Here are ContentView and Content2
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(value: $model.myDatas) {
                    Text(String(model.myDatas.value))
                }
            }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct Content2: View {
    @Binding var data: MyData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(data.value))
            Button { data.value += 1 } label: { Text("Increment") }
        }
    }
}

In the Content2 view, although data.value gets incremented, the view isn't refreshed for reasons that I don't understand, but removing the .navigationDestination() and replacing the NavigationLink(value: ,label:) with NavigationLink(destination: ,label:) makes it work fine.

Binding does not work with that navigationDestination you have to use the is presented one
